# How does a process calibrator source a resistance?

Tags: circuit-design, multimeter

I have a Fluke 743b Documenting Process Calibrator. It is capable of measuring and sourcing current, voltage, and resistance (and a few other things that are out of scope of this question). It has a keypad where I can select "source" or "measure," select resistance, voltage, or current, and type the desired value. I'd like to understand the basics of how process calibrators like this work. I can find schematics of various multimeters and power supplies, so have some idea of how a process calibrator might source current and voltage, but how does sourcing resistance work? Is is likely a bunch of digital potentiometers, or something else?

Comment: I'd like you to talk about traceability to NIST or DIN (Deutsches Institut für Normung) for example. Accuracy must be traceable. How many steps between a standard organization and your point of calibration are there? Talk about what you know of the process. Your apparent lack of certainty worries me somewhat.

Comment: To find how the Fluke 743b works, consult the manual. The information should be there. If not then call Fluke for information. To have confidence in the calibration knowledge of your equipment is imperative. Looking into other equipment for how yours works does not make sense. Just because it is showing its age doesn’t mean that there is something better.

Comment: Our company manufactures gas detection instruments. Our products include purchased sensors, and the final product is calibrated using gas mixtures that are certified for accuracy. So, our measurement traceability is through the calibration gasses, not through multimeters.

Comment: In our production process, multimeters are used (1) to measure current consumption of handheld products and determine whether battery life will meet specification and (2) by repair technicians for general troubleshooting. Neither application requires NIST or DIN traceability. Whether we still need to verify multimeter accuracy for those applications is an interesting question, though it is not what I asked.

Comment: By "showing its age," I mean that the Fluke's battery no longer accepts a charge, the DC power port is loose, and when the device is calibrated, the "as found" condition is almost always out of tolerance, indicating that the device's accuracy is no longer maintained through our calibration interval.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main methods for simulating resistance. One is to use a bunch of precision resistors which are switched. The second assumes some reasonable range of currents and a maximum frequency that will be applied by the DUT, and uses circuitry to simulate the resistance by (for example) measuring the applied current and outputting a voltage that corresponds to what would appear across the simulated resistance.

Precise electronics costs money, and the cost increases exponentially as you approach state of the art. You normally want the calibrator to be the most accurate and stable device in your shop. It has to hold calibration within specs between external calibrations and has to be accurate enough that it can be used to calibrate other instruments.

For example, a 0.1% 25ppm/°C resistor might be a penny or two in quantity, but a 0.01% 0.2ppm/°C resistor might be more like $50+ so 3,000x the cost for 10x the initial accuracy and 100x the temperature stability. Voltage references show similar ratios. An ovenized buried zener voltage reference can easily be more than $100.

There is little volume need for such precise components, which also is a reason for higher prices. In cases where a high-volume need materializes they can often figure out a way to make the part much more cheaply (though it still will generally command a handsome premium over an ordinary part). An example of that would be the low-cost barometer MEMS sensors (and single package IMUs).